# Cохранить текст с определенной строки

Tags: c#

У меня есть текст. Я хочу часто добавлять в него строки или удалять.

У меня больше вопрос не в том, как сохранить с определенной строки, а в том, можно ли это сделать точечно, не загружая весь файл каждый раз и пересохраняя его? Потому что добавление/удаление строк будет происходить часто. Или хотя бы как сделать это наиболее оптимизированно?

На данный момент у меня имеется вот что:

```
List<string> contentList = new List<string>();
// Здесь наполняется контент для вставки
foreach (var str in data) {                                
    contentList.Add(str);
}

string filePath = "ПУТЬ_ДО_ФАЙЛА.txt";
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();    
lines.Insert(0, string.Empty);
int lineNumberToPaste = lines.FindIndex(line => line.Contains("##CONTENT##"));

lines.InsertRange(lineNumberToPaste + 1, contentList);
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines.ToArray());
```

Comment: Вариант с "хранить в памяти,а по завершении работы программы сохранить"  не подходит?

Comment: @TEA нет, потому что по-сути это лпанируется генерируемый partial class, который будет взаимодействовать с другим файлом

Comment: @ИгорьПоляков, не совсем понятно, что значит взаимодействовать, что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @SerafimProzorov самая хорошая аналогия - это windows forms. Там в одном файле объявлются элементы,в другом обработчики висят и пишется своя логика. Думаю это самое точное описание того, что планирую достичь

Comment: @ИгорьПоляков, тогда не совсем ясно, почему нельзя работать с файлами, как со структурами данных в памяти, в чем все же состоит Ваша задача? Чем подробнее Вы опишете задачу, тем больше вероятности, что Вам помогут.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov "почему нельзя работать с файлами, как со структурами данных в памяти" - видимо потому, что пользователь будет иметь возможность редактировать второй файл и нужно знать, какие компоненты доступны. Задача полностью описана в вопросе. Хранить в памяти до завершения работы программы - не вариант. Всё.

Comment: Чтоб не читать весь текстовой файл и не держать всю коллекцию данных в памяти, а тем более писать в файл в отдельные нужные места вам для этого придется самостоятельно написать довольно объемную вещь. Проще взять NoSQL БД [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB#litedb---a-net-nosql-document-store-in-a-single-data-file) и работать с ней.

Comment: @Bulson То есть, по сути, если я хочу не БД, а именно постоянное взаимодействие с файлом и этот файл не десятки тысяч строк, то мой код вполне себе приемлемый?